# get rid of red X in IE for non-existing images

Tags: internet-explorer, image

I have a 3rd website (Confluence) which references images which are secured by a login.

If the current user is logged in the image is shown if not the image url would redirect to a login form.

Example

```
<img src="secure/myimage.gif" />
```

When you enter this url in the browser a redirect to the login page is done.

The problem now: IE shows a the dreaded red X icon for the image even though there should be just nothing (like in Firefox). Anyone knows how to get around this?

Comment: Different browsers have always rendered broken images differently. You'll notice you get a broken image icon in Safari and Chrome too, and Opera gives the text “Image” if there's no alt text. (WebKit doesn't use the alt text at all for broken images, which is a bit poor.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [`onError`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197053(v=VS.85).aspx) event to set a default image.

This will function in any browser.

The blank image show in FF is a quirk of FF because the received file isn't an image it should report an error.

Comment: Or remove the image completely if you don't want anything, eg.: `onerror="this.parentNode.removeChild(this)"`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I'm using this jQuery script to replace all broken images with a defined placeholder image. Works in IE/FF/Chrome:

<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

jQuery(window).bind('load', function() {
jQuery('img').each(function() {
    if((typeof this.naturalWidth != "undefined" &&
        this.naturalWidth == 0 ) 
        || this.readyState == 'uninitialized' ) {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', 'placeholder.gif');
    }
}); 
})



</script>

Comment: Works perfect, Cheers! `<img src="pic.jpg" onerror="this.src='default.jpg'"/>`

Answer (score 2):

Here are some solutions:

1. redirect the page that contains secured images to the login form
2. the image service returns a default one if security check failed.
3. ship a hacked IE to your client with the red X replaced by a blank one like Firefox you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

I found a fine solution using jQuery:
This script replaces all "broken" images with a defined placeholder. Works perfect in IE/FF/Chrome

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="javascript">

jQuery(window).bind('load', function() {
jQuery('img').each(function() {
    if((typeof this.naturalWidth != "undefined" &&
        this.naturalWidth == 0 ) 
        || this.readyState == 'uninitialized' ) {
        jQuery(this).attr('src', 'placeholder.gif');
    }
}); 
})

</script>
```